How does autocompletion work for python modules (especially pybind11 modules)?
I'm coming back to using pybind11 after about a year off. I'm finding the autocompletion features for modules built using pybind11 don't seem to work anymore. Not in iPython in a terminal window, or a console in pycharm. I swear this used to work, and a similiar question on stackoverflow indicates that it should.
The only difference to what I'm doing as compared to what I did before is that I'm building the modules using a makefile instead of cmake. This is because of an obscure bug with cmake and pybind11 and macOS that apparently is new. And I'm not fond of cmake anyway, so I'm relieved not to have to use it anymore, and it turns out that using a makefile is quite simple. My theory is that there is some byproduct of the build that should contain the autocomplete information that is not being created when I build using a makefile. Hence my question about how this all works under the hood. Any references would be appreciated.
Here is the makefile I'm using:
INCLUDE := $(shell python3 -m pybind11 --includes)
FLAG := -g -O0 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -fPIC
SUFFIX := $(shell python3-config --extension-suffix)
demo:
    c++ $(FLAG) $(INCLUDE) pybind_streaming.cpp -o pybind_streaming$(SUFFIX)


Perhaps the old CMake setup had typing stub (.pyi) generation hooked in? There's https://github.com/sizmailov/pybind11-stubgen that does it as well, that you could use. IIRC some things (several IDEs) don't like to inspect binary Python modules, and need pre-generated stubs instead.
